# htmlagilitypack identify inconsistancy

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I use htmlagilitypack & xpath.

How can I identify insconsistancy in html. For example:

```
<table><tr><td>
<b>Car1</b><span>Color123</span>
<bCar2</b><span>Color333</span>
<b>Car3</b><span>Color221</span>
<b>Car4 <span>Color224</span>
<b>Car5</b><span>Color621</span>
</table></tr></td>
```

Car2 & Car4 bold are broken.

The problem is that i use root.SelectNodes("//b[1]")[Index] and it misses index position2 (Car2) and put on its place Car3 and I don't even know that such thing happened if i don't inspect the results manually. At least, i need to have "empty" position2 (Car2) and a correct position3 (Car3).

HtmlAgility pack can't indetify and fix it automatically. doc.ParseErrors can't identify it.

Can you offer some combination of XPath functions like Substring, Boolean, Concat, Number etc.? I'm not good enough in XPath, but I feel that these functions can help in identifying inconsistancy.

p.s. Html Tidy library can't fix it. It sometimes decides that:

```
<b>Car4 <span>Color224</span></b>
```

Which is not the correct fix.

Comment: @user569008: You need a proper XML tree to use XPath. The parser will provide you those errors. There are some parsers that can take an HTML document and translate to XML inferring proper structure. But that's not the same as emending an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlDocumemt.ParseErrors does contains 3 errors for your example:

```
 - Start tag <b> was not found (because there is a closing b without an opening one)
 - Start tag <tr> was not found (because the tr is inside an opening b without a closing one)
 - Start tag <td> was not found (same as tr)
```

In the general case, it's impossible to 1) identify errors the way you want, and 2) much more difficult to fix them. You would have to exactly define what's the expected format.

You can use the Html Agility Pack to identify errors with specific requirements. For example here is a piece of code, that validates your doc, base on the functional requirement that "every child element of a TD must be a B or a SPAN and must not contain more than one grand child element":

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("MyFile.htm");

    foreach (HtmlNode childOfTd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/*"))
    {
        if ((childOfTd.Name != "b") && (childOfTd.Name != "span") || (childOfTd.ChildNodes.Count > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("child error, outerHtml=" + childOfTd.OuterHtml);
        }
    }
```

To fix this requires raw text access (maybe a Regex, and BTW, a Regex can also identify simple errors) because the Html Agility Pack builds a DOM that does not let you access incorrect syntax nodes, by design.

Comment: Don't pay attention to <tr> and <td> I've mistaken their positions (but it correctly identify them and also correctly find their LinePosition property). About <b> tags - 1) It didn't correctly evaluate LinePosition property of the missing opening <b> tag, 1.1) it didn't automatically fix the error, so there's no use of it 2) It didn't find the second missing closing </b> tag, because it's not an error. My goal is looping through with foreach and SelelectedNodes collection and XPath functions to determine, where LinePosition or TagPosition in order to fix it. Is it possible with CSharp & Xpath?

Comment: About RegEx, i know it's powerful, and it couldn't be done but, my question is - if it's possible to do it with htmlagility/cs/xpath alone, without the help of RegEx or XSLT? Also, HTMLagilitypack builds a DOM, but it builds it wrong, when it misses or don't fixes some tags. Simon, u really help me a lot with your examples, thank you very much for your help, if you pass some other ideas identifying bold tags, i'll appreciate it.